# Removing certain end-standing values from list in Python

Tags: python, list

Is there an elegant Pythonic way to perform something like `rstrip()` on a list?

Imagine, I have different lists:

```
l1 = ['A', 'D', 'D']
l2 = ['A', 'D']
l3 = ['D', 'A', 'D', 'D']
l4 = ['A', 'D', 'B', 'D']
```

I need a function that will remove *all end-standing* `'D'` elements from a given list (but not those that come before or in between other elements!).

```
for mylist in [l1, l2, l3, l4]:
    print(mylist, ' => ', remove_end_elements(mylist, 'D'))
```

So the desired output would be:

```
['A', 'D', 'D'] => ['A']
['A', 'D'] => ['A']
['D', 'A', 'D', 'D'] => ['D', 'A']
['A', 'D', 'B', 'D'] => ['A','D','B']
```

One implementation that does the job is this:

```
def remove_end_elements(mylist, myelement):
    counter = 0
    for element in mylist[::-1]:
        if element != myelement:
            break
        counter -= 1

    return mylist[:counter]
```

Is there a more elegant / efficient way to do it?

To answer comment-questions:

- Either a new list or modifying the original list is fine (although the above implementation has creating a new list in mind).
- The real lists contain multi-character-strings (lines from a text file).
- What I'm actually trying to strip away are lines that fulfill certain criteria for "empty" (no characters OR only whitespace OR only whitespace and commas). I have that check implemented elsewhere.
- These empty lines can be an arbitrary number at the end of the list, but in most cases will be 1.

---

I timed the different solutions offered so far, with simulated data close to my actual use case, and the actual is_empty_line() function that I'm using:

- [Kelly Bundy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77786049/1413513): 0.029670200019609183
- [Guy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77781070/1413513): 0.038380099984351546
- my original solution: 0.03837349999230355
- [cards' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77785322/1413513): 0.0408437000005506
- [Timeless' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77781188/1413513): 0.08083210000768304

Which one performs better does seem to depend on the complexity of the `is_empty_line()` function (except for Timeless' solution, which is consistently slower than everything else, and KellyBundy's solution, which is consistently faster).

Comment: is the list single characters?

Comment: a _single_ in-place rstrip can be done with `list(iter(l.pop, 'D'))`

Comment: @cards That wrongly turns `['C', 'A', 'R', 'D', 'S']` into `['C', 'A', 'R']`.

Comment: @Kelly Bundy you are right, thank you for pointing that out, and nice example by the way. It seems more that can be _used_ as a kind of `rpartition`. Sorry for the fake news

Comment: I'm curious how you modified the solutions to work with your is_empty_line() function. Could you share your benchmark script?

Comment: @KellyBundy sure. Added it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def remove_end_elements(mylist, myelement):
    while myelement in mylist[-1:]:
        mylist.pop()
    return mylist
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the elegant solution I was looking for. (Although it does modify the original list unlike the other answers; but as I specified in an edit, this is okay for my usecase.)

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the list in reverse to find the last index that is not `param` and return a slice of the list

```
def remove_end_elements(my_list, param):
    if not my_list or my_list[-1] != param:
        return my_list
    for i, x in enumerate(my_list[::-1]):
        if x != param:
            return my_list[:-i]
    return []
```

Answer (score 1):

As requested by @KellyBundy: this is my benchmarking script for the various solutions offered.
(All solutions adjusted to closer resemble my actual usecase.)

```
import timeit

statement = """

lines = ['ABCDEFGHIJ'] * 100
lines += [' ', ',, ,']

def line_is_empty_row(line: str) -> bool:
    if line.replace(",", "").strip() == "":
        return True
    return False
"""

imp1 = """
def remove_empty_rows_from_end(lines: list[str]) -> list[str]:
    counter = 0
    for line in lines[::-1]:
        if line_is_empty_row(line):
            counter -= 1
        else:
            break
    return lines[:counter]

result = remove_empty_rows_from_end(lines)
"""

imp2 = """
def remove_end_elements(my_list):
    if not my_list or not line_is_empty_row(my_list[-1]):
        return my_list
    for i, line in enumerate(my_list[::-1]):
        if not line_is_empty_row(line):
            return my_list[:-i]
    return []

result = remove_end_elements(lines)
"""

imp3 = """
def rstrip(lst):
    enum = reversed(list(enumerate(lst, start=1)))
    upto = next((i for i, line in enum if not line_is_empty_row(line)), 0)
    return lst[:upto]

result = rstrip(lines)
"""

imp4 = """
from itertools import groupby

def list_rstrip(my_list):
    line, i = next(groupby(reversed(my_list)))
    return my_list[:-len(list(i))] if line_is_empty_row(line) else my_list

result = list_rstrip(lines)
"""

imp5 = """
def remove_end_elements(mylist):
    while mylist and line_is_empty_row(mylist[-1]):
        mylist.pop()
    return mylist

result = remove_end_elements(lines)
"""

num = 10000

print("Kelly Bundy", timeit.timeit(statement + imp5, number=num))
print("Guy", timeit.timeit(statement + imp2, number=num))
print("mine", timeit.timeit(statement + imp1, number=num))
print("cards", timeit.timeit(statement + imp4, number=num))
print("Timeless", timeit.timeit(statement + imp3, number=num))
```

Comment: Your modified groupby solution isn't right, only removes one of the empty lines (because they differ). I suggest `groupby(reversed(my_list), key=line_is_empty_row)`.

Answer (score 0):

A possible option with *slicing* :

```
def rstrip(lst, item="D"):
    enum = reversed(list(enumerate(lst, start=1)))
    upto = next((i for i, v in enum if v != item), 0)
    return lst[:upto]
```

Output :

```
for l in (l1, l2, l3, l4):
    print(f"{l!s:<22}", rstrip(l), sep="=>  ")
    
['A', 'D', 'D']       =>  ['A']
['A', 'D']            =>  ['A']
['D', 'A', 'D', 'D']  =>  ['D', 'A']
['A', 'D', 'B', 'D']  =>  ['A', 'D', 'B']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.groupby` to "hide" all the index/counting technicality.

```
from itertools import groupby


def list_rstrip(l, char='D'):
    grp_id, grp = next(groupby(reversed(l)))
    return (l[:-len(list(grp))] if grp_id == char else l)
```